# creating a bottom bar menu

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I am looking into ways of building a bottom menu bar in android. I was initially planning to make use of splitting the action bar with the uiOptions:splitWhenNarrow but unfortunately that  only applies to phone screens.

I am aiming to design for nexus 7, so slightly bigger screen!

I came across one tutorial which I've linked below. It seems like just the thing I was looking for but before I dive into the coding I just wanted to check whether it's a good way of doing such a thing?

Perhaps someone can suggest an alternative? I'm relatively new to android so this is a huge learning curve for me and I am trying to develop based on the best practices.

Many thanks.

http://www.paxmodept.com/telesto/blogitem.htm?id=810

*The menu bar in the tutorial is pretty much what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: yea, just use a linear layout containing your buttons, which is anchored to bottom of screen. Thats the way to go. :)

Comment: just a suggestion as you are new Android eco-system, read the following guideline 'Don't use bottom tab bars': http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html